# Direct product of Rings isomorphism

Tags: ring-theory

I was reading chapter five in my Abstrat algebra book about finite Abelian groups. In Proposition 6 part (1). It states that $Z_{m}  \times Z_{n} \cong Z_{mn}$ if and only if $gcd(m,n)=1$. This proposition i understand it. Now the question that i want to ask is suppose we were working in a Ring instead of a group, does this proposition also apply. in order words, will these two rings $Z_{m}  \times Z_{n} \cong Z_{mn}$  be isomorphic to one another if their $gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: what about addition, does phi preserves addition also

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was incorrect. Please ignore it.

Comment: The isomorphism $\phi: Z_{mn} \to Z_m \times Z_n$ is actually given by $a \mapsto (a \pmod m, a \pmod n)$, and you can check that this map preserves multiplication.

Comment: If your book does not say that you ask is very likely that the answer is NO. Check this for the addition

Comment: i did but i was not sure it was alright that is one of the main reason i end up asking this question, i saw that the multiplication works but not the addition i thought that i had did something wrong

Comment: @ Luis Sanchez Gomez: What do you mean that the answer is no? It is a very well-known theorem (Chinese Remainder theorem) that $Z_m \times Z_m$ and $Z_{mn}$ are isomorphic as rings. The isomorphism is given as above. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement